# Container restart on Exception in GCP VM Instance but not locally or on AWS

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a service running within a Docker container on a Google Cloud Platform (GCP) VM instance with *Container-Optimized OS 109-17800.66.27 stable*

This service establishes WebSocket connections with multiple clients. However, I'm encountering a peculiar issue where GCP kills and restarts the container whenever an exception occurs within the service. Strangely, I don't observe this behavior when running the service locally or on AWS.

- The service is built within a Docker container and connects to clients via WebSockets.
- When an exception is encountered within the service, GCP terminates the container.
- This behavior is not replicated when the same service is run on local environments or on AWS; the container remains active even after encountering exceptions.

I've checked for any automatic restart policies or configurations within GCP but haven't found anything explicitly causing this behavio (I can change the restart policy but whatever I choose always kills the container.)

Why does GCP automatically kill the container upon encountering exceptions, while local environments or AWS do not exhibit this behavior?
What configurations or settings within GCP could be causing this behavior, and how can I mitigate it to prevent container termination?

Any insights or guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Which service are you using to run the container? You tagged `google-compute-engine` but there are two very different implementations. Docker on Compute Engine and Container Optimized OS (COS). Add details on what you are using and how you are running the container. Suggestion: never allow unhandled exceptions in your software.

Comment: I use "Container-Optimized OS 109-17800.66.27 stable". I have updated my question. Thanks for your advice, normally I don't leave exceptions and it will disappear but I wanted to understand the behaviour of the container on both platforms.

Comment: IIRC, COS restarts your container on unhandled exceptions. Docker on Compute Engine does not.

Comment: Docker policy for restarting containers: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/